# Units of Activation Energy

Tags: kinetics, concentration, energy

Consider the reaction
$$\ce{aA + bB -> cC + dD}$$ whose reactants are given by A and B and the products are C and D.

Say the activation energy of this reaction is some $x$ joules/mole, But moles of what ( $A$ or $B$ or $C$ or $D$) ?

If I need $x$ joules of energy to react $A$ with $B$ with the correct orientation, To react $a$ moles of $A$, I would need $ax$ Joules of energy, if it was $x$ joules of energy to react $B$ with $A$, I would need $bx$ amount of energy to react $b$ moles of $B$. Since the reaction is the same the amount of energy needed should be constant to react a fixed concentration of reactants. I know I am missing some understanding here.

Comment: Think of it as "moles of reaction". If there are x moles of reaction, then xa moles of A react with xb moles of B.

Comment: Per mole of species in transition state.

Comment: To form 1 mole of TS?

Comment: @BuckThorn So to form c moles of C and d moles of D from a moles of A and b moles of B, I need x joules of energy?

Comment: If it is activation energy, you need that amount but will get some back. In general, molar quantities are per mole of reaction (enthalpy of reaction, Gibbs energy of reaction).

Comment: You won't need x Joules, you'll need x times the activation energy per mole (the activation energy will be in units of energy per moles of reaction).

Comment: It is the thermal energy (kinetic , vibrational /rotational). Very, very occasionally, by Boltzmann distribution, a pair of molecules have enough of this energy to react. We make this into a per mole basis for ease of comparison and usage with other molar quantities.